# Removing Middle of Filename

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I wish to remove the middle of filenames that look like the following:

```
Wm-no-Bis.GAGATTCC-ATAGAGGC.L001.R1.001.fastq.trim.R2.fastq
Pek-no-Bis.GAGATTCC-AGGCGAAG.L001.R1.001.fastq.trim.R1.fastq
```

To Get

```
Wm-no-Bis.trim.R2.fastq
Pek-no-Bis.trim.R1.fastq
```

As you can see the beginning and end of the files are slightly variable.
I have attempted to use rename as follows:

```
rename 's/.*.*.*.*.*.trim.//g'
Wm-no-Bis.GAGATTCC-ATAGAGGC.L001.R1.001.fastq.trim.R2copy.fastq
```

This removes the entire file name except for the end.
The issue is obviously my lack of understanding how to use wildcards.

Comment: What is expected filenames after rename?

Comment: Edited to include desired output

Comment: *"The issue is obviously my lack of understanding how to use wildcards."*: The solution is to read a regex tutorial.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rename command doesn't use regexes, and it also doesn't support complex globbing or anything like this.  You probably want to try to use sed or something for this purpose.

Comment: @Taywee: the *rename* utility in question is the one written by Larry Wall and fully supports Perl regexes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Depends on the rename utility.  Mine, installed from my Gentoo util-linux package, does not support regexes.  edit: [it's this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).  OP never mentioned explicitly that they were using the Perl one, though their attempt to use regexes would imply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/^([^.]+).*(\.trim\..*)$/$1$2/' *.fastq
```

When you're happy with output then remove `-n` option (dry-run)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
rename 's/\.\w+-\w+\..{4}\.R.\.\d{3}\.fastq//g'
```

[source](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rename/)