# Remove middle of filenames

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have a list of filenames like this in bash

```
UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
```

And I want them to look like this

```
UTSHoS10_R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS10_R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_R1.fq.gz 
UTSHoS11_R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_R2.fq.gz
```

I do not have the perl `rename` command and `sed 's/_Other*160418./_/' *.gz`
is not doing anything. I've tried other rename scripts on here but either nothing occurs or my shell starts printing huge amounts of code to the console and freezes.

This post ([Removing Middle of Filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103875/removing-middle-of-filename)) is similar however the answers given do not explain what specific parts of the command are doing so I could not apply it to my problem.

Comment: Note that sed will run on the *contents* of the supplied files, not their names. That's why your sed command doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in the directory which contains the files to be renamed:

```
for file_name in *.gz
do 
  new_file_name=$(sed 's/_[^.]*\./_/g' <<< "$file_name");
  mv "$file_name" "$new_file_name";
done
```

The pattern (`_[^.]*\.`) starts matching from the FIRST `_` till the FIRST `.` (both inclusive). `[^.]*` means 0 or more non-dot (or non-period) characters.

Example:

```
AMD$ ls
UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz  UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz  UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz

AMD$ for file_name in *.gz
> do new_file_name=$(sed 's/_[^.]*\./_/g' <<< "$file_name")
> mv "$file_name" "$new_file_name"
> done

AMD$ ls
UTSHoS10_R1.fq.gz  UTSHoS10_R2.fq.gz  UTSHoS11_R2.fq.gz  UTSHoS12_R1.fq.gz  UTSHoS12_R2.fq.gz
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. The only thing I don't understand is how this section of code `_[^.]*\.` in the `sed` command is specifying the pattern in my filenames...

Comment: This pattern starts matching from the FIRST `_` till the FIRST `.` (both inclusive). `[^.]*` means 0 or more non-dot (or non-period) characters

Comment: I can't make this work, it spits: "No such file or directory".  This is my code: file_name=Screenshot_2020-08-06-16-13-43-731_com.tclhz.gallery.jpg
new_file_name=$(sed 's/_[^.]*\./_/g' <<< "$file_name");
mv "$file_name" "$new_file_name";

Answer (score 5):

[Parameter expansions in `bash`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) can perform string substitutions based on glob-like patterns, which allows for a more efficient solution than calling an extra external utility such as `sed` in each loop iteration:

```
for f in *.gz; do echo mv "$f" "${f/_Other_*-TTAGGA_R_160418./_}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` before `mv` to perform actual renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash, using substring operation and assuming that all file names have the same length:

```
for file in UTS*.gz; do
  echo mv -i "$file" "${file:0:9}${file:38:8}"
done
```

Outputs:

```
mv -i UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz UTSHoS10_R1.fq.gz
mv -i UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz UTSHoS10_R2.fq.gz
mv -i UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz UTSHoS11_R2.fq.gz
mv -i UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz UTSHoS11_R2.fq.gz
mv -i UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz UTSHoS12_R1.fq.gz
mv -i UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz UTSHoS12_R2.fq.gz
```

Once verified, remove `echo` from the line inside the loop and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Going with your sed command, this can work as a bash one-liner:

```
for name in UTSH*fq.gz; do newname=$(echo $name | sed 's/_Other.*160418\./_/'); echo mv $name $newname; done
```

Notes:

- I've adjusted your sed command: it had an `*` without a preceeding `.` (sed takes a regular expression, not a globbing pattern). Similarly, the dot needs escaping.
- To see if it works, without actually renaming the files, I've left the `echo` command in. Easy to remove just that to make it functional.
- It doesn't have to be a one-liner, obviously. But sometimes, that makes editing and browsing your command-line history easier.

Comment: Other solutions could use bash string substitutions, but since you tagged your question with sed and already had a sed pattern, I've gone with that.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in *.gz; do mv "$i" "${i%O*}${i#*.}"; done

input:
UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS10_Other_CAAGCC-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_Other_AGGCCT-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_Other_GGCAAG-TTAGGA_R_160418.R2.fq.gz

output:
UTSHoS10_R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS10_R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS11_R2.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_R1.fq.gz
UTSHoS12_R2.fq.gz
```

Comment: You should add explanation.